# Let $X_{x,1}$ and $X_{x,2} $be two unbiased estimators for a real parameter $X$

Tags: probability, estimation

Let $X_{x,1}$ and $X_{x,2} $be two unbiased estimators for a real parameter $X$.
Let us define $X_{x}=\alpha X_{x,1}+\beta X_{x,2}$ with $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$.

For which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the estimator $X_{x}$ unbiased?

For which value(s) of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the estimator $X_{x}$ found above of minimal variance? We assume that $X_{x,1}$ and $X_{x,2}$ are independent and that $\mathrm{Var}(X_{x,1})=\mathrm{Var}(X_{x,2})=\sigma^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation here is pretty suboptimal. But the idea here is as follows: in order for $X_x$ to unbiased for some (fixed) parameter $X$, we would desire that
$$
X=E(X_x)=E(\alpha X_{x,1}+\beta X_{x,2})=\alpha E(X_{x_,1})+\beta E(X_{x,2})=(\alpha+\beta)X.
$$
The last equality above uses the unbiasedness of $X_{x,1}$ and $X_{x,2}$. So the answer is: if $X=0$, then for **all** $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $X_x$ is unbiased for $X$; on the other hand, if $X\neq 0$, then $X_x$ is unbiased for $X$ if and only if $\alpha+\beta=1$.

For simplicity, I will assume away the probably unintended case of $X=0$. Then:
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_x)=(\alpha^2+\beta^2)\sigma^2.
$$
Given $\alpha+\beta=1$, can you minimize 
$$
\alpha^2+\beta^2=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\beta)^2?
$$